# How can I restart the airflow server on Google Composer?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, airflow, google-cloud-composer

When I need to restart the webserver locally I do:

```
ps -ef | grep airflow | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
airflow webserver -p 8080 -D
```

How can I do this on Google Composer? I don't see an option to restart the server in the console.

Comment: Why do you want to restart? I think that [this command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/) can cover the function you are looking for.

Comment: @RubénC. When I change a plugin, it doesn't seem to take effect until I restart the server. Which of those commands will restart the server? `update`?

Comment: While you'd normally need to restart the webserver to pick up plugins when running Airflow locally, The managed Airflow webserver in Composer automatically loads plugins uploaded to the environment's Cloud Storage bucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Cloud Composer is an Apache Airflow [managed service](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/), it is not possible to restart the whole service. You can restart though the single instances of the service, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/restarting-an-instance), but this will not help to apply to the plugin changes.

To apply the plugin changes, you should [install the plugin](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/plugins#installing_a_plugin) after loading it into the `plugin` folder, automatically created when you created the environment:

```
gcloud composer environments storage plugins import --environment ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
    --location LOCATION \
    --source PATH_TO_LOCAL_FILE \
    --destination PATH_IN_SUBFOLDER
```

DAG updates are performed automatically and some other must be applied using

`gcloud composer environments update`

[command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/update).

Answer (score 24):

A way to restart Composer server is to add a 'dummy variable' into the 'Environment Variables' of GCP Composer UI. After submitting, it will restart to include this change.
[image]

Comment: This worked for Composer 2+

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: Only works for 1.13.1 >= Composer version < 2.0.0

Restarting the Airflow has recently been introduced as a feature in preview [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/accessing/airflow-web-interface#restarting).

TL;DR the command is:

```sh
gcloud beta composer environments restart-web-server ENVIRONMENT_NAME
  --location=LOCATION
```

Comment: As of Jan. 2022 this does not work for Composer > 2

`(gcloud.beta.composer.environments.restart-web-server) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Web server restart feature is not supported for Cloud Composer version 2.0.0 or newer.`